# Can't run "gulp trust-dev-cert". Error "cannot read "tostring" of null"

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, gulp, gulp-trust-dev-cert

I am trying to build up a react web part for SharePoint, and I was following the instructions from Microsoft page :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part

On my personal PC it worked just fine, but in the office computer , whenever I try to run `gulp trust-dev-cert` I get this:

`C:\Users\ms327\Desktop\teste>gulp trust-dev-cert
Build target: DEBUG
[09:19:12] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\teste\gulpfile.js
[09:19:12] Starting gulp
[09:19:12] Starting 'trust-dev-cert'...
[09:19:12] Starting subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig'...
[09:19:12] Finished subtask 'configure-sp-build-rig' after 32 ms
[09:19:12] Starting subtask 'trust-cert'...
[09:19:25] Error - [trust-cert] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[09:19:25] Error - 'trust-cert' sub task errored after 13 s
 Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[09:19:25] 'trust-dev-cert' errored after 13 s
[09:19:25]
[09:19:26] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [trust-cert] TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null
Error - 'trust-cert' sub task errored after 13 s
 Cannot read property 'toString' of null
[09:19:26] Project teste version:0.0.1
[09:19:26] Build tools version:3.9.26
[09:19:26] Node version:v8.16.0
[09:19:26] Total duration:47 s
[09:19:26] Task errors:2`

Have already tried to run on Node `8.*`, `10.*`, deleted everything I could find about node on PC to make a clean reinstall, and I cant get through it.

If I run `gulp serve` it works, but I cannot see my web part on SharePoint workbench.

Everything I find about this problem is related to node version. But already tried changing it several times.

even deleted `.gcb-serve-data` from the root folder.

Any suggestion?

what can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in the helloworld-webpart folder. If you have followed the instructions first you need to enter the folder

```
cd helloworld-webpart
```

Then Execute

```
gulp trust-dev-cert
```

Comment: yeap.. I did tried to run gulp-trust-dev-cert on my project folder. it was the "C:\Users\ms327\Desktop\teste" folder.. changed the name of the project